# How to focus on element that loads after page load

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using the following hack-ish approach to focus on the Stripe input element after it's loaded:

```
<div id="card-element">
  <!-- Load stripe stuff here -->
</div>

// <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
card.mount('#card-element');

setTimeout(function(){
    card.focus();
},1000);
```

Is there a better way to do, i.e., to detect when the `card` element is 'focus-able'. If I do it on page-load, it just doesn't see the element (it probably hasn't been added yet, and so it doesn't work).

Here's an example element: https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/ (I wasn't able to paste a working example into jsfiddle, as I wasn't sure how to load an external library).

Comment: Simply execute a `click()` programmatically on the containing DOM node. This will automatically focus the card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#element-on) you can attach a listener on the element and then call focus when it has mounted.

Not tested code but should look something like this

```
 card.on('ready', function(){
    card.focus();
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks, what is the difference between using `ready` or using `load`? Previously i was trying to use load.

Comment: I'm not sure if it exists a load event to listen for. I'm not that experienced with stripe tho so I might be wrong.