# When are stripe elements ready in the dom?

Tags: javascript, iframe, stripe-payments

I am using [Stripe elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) in a Vue component. The elements show nicely in a card, but now I would like to put a v-show on the card when the elements are all 'ready/ mounted'. My question: Is there a way to determine when the elements are completely ready?

I tried something along these lines in an async 'createElement' component method:

```
this.paymentRequestButton.mount('#payment-request-button')
this.card.mount('#card-element')
this.stripeElementsReady = true
```

The elements do show but this.stripeElementsReady triggers too early, or can iframe elements not be timed precisely as they are asynchronous 'by nature' or something? BTW I do use await for the actual stripe requests so that should not cause the issue.

Comment: The given answer here is an exact copy of the dupe link, with the same answerer. Instead of accept and upvote this answer, upvote the dupe links answer and allow for the answerer to delete this one, as award copy-paste answers makes no one happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883314/6749142)

As per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#element-on) you can attach a listener on the element and then call focus when it has mounted.

Not tested code but should look something like this

```
card.on('ready', function(){
    card.focus();
    }
)
```

Comment: We don't answer with a _"check out this answer"_, nor do a copy-paste from another, SO has a built-in "vote/flag to close as a duplicate" function for a reason.

Comment: Ok. The reasoning behind I answered the way I did is that I think this question is better suited for future searches as it is more accurate than the one in the other thread. Also it's my answer in the other thread.

Comment: I know it is your answer but that doesn't matter (and is actually worse to provide the same twice), and the dupe link will actually increase this question's chance being found, just because it being a dupe ... and so will your first answer, as they now are linked.

Comment: Oh didn't think of it that way. Makes sense tho. I will do the way you explained from now on :)